# req.headers('Authorization') is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble with this code because token is returning undefined.

In my frontend:

```
export const fetchUser = async (token: any) => {
        const res = await axios.post('/user/getuser', {
            headers: {Authorization : token}
        });
        return res;
};
```

And in my middleware is:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';

const auth = (req: Request | any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers('Authorization');
        console.log(token);
        if(!token) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Invalid Authentication.'});

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string, (err: any, user: any) => {
            if(err) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Invalid Authentication token"})

            req.user = user;

            next();

        });
    } catch (error: any) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: error.message});
    }
}
module.exports = auth;
```

I've tested it in Postman and there's no problem, however there's a problem when I make requests from my frontend.

Comment: Can you check the request from network tab in dev tools and confirm whether `Authorization` header exists under request headers.

Comment: You aren't passing a token to the `fetchUser` function. **Why** you aren't passing a token (or are passing undefined) to the `fetchUser` function is your real problem.

Comment: I am passing a token in the fetchUser, I console.log the token before passing it and the token exists. However, in the auth middleware, I tried to console log the token being passed and then it returns undefined. I have solved the problem by accessing the token in the middleware as req.body.headers.Authorization because the header isn't working. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
req.headers.authorization
```

This way you can get the auth object from the request header and get the value from it.

I did the as above and it worked well with no problem, try that please. I

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).